# How to convert from toggle to onclick

Tags: javascript, html

I have a three element span that toggles between the elements, but would like to chage it to an onclick event instead. Any idea as to how this can be accomplished?

```
"tap .date-toggle": function () {
    var which
    if (this.$(".toggle-today").hasClass("active")) {
        $(".toggle-today").removeClass("active")
        $(".toggle-yesterday").addClass("active")
        which = "yesterday"
    } else if (this.$(".toggle-yesterday").hasClass("active")) {
        $(".toggle-yesterday").removeClass("active")
        $(".toggle-WTD").addClass("active")
        which = "WTD"
    } else if (this.$(".toggle-WTD").hasClass("active")) {
        $(".toggle-WTD").removeClass("active")
        $(".toggle-today").addClass("active")
        which = "today"
    }
    this.trigger("switchSalesDate", which, _.bind(this.updateSalesList, this));
},

<div class="date-toggle">
    <span class="toggle-today active">Today</span> 
    | 
    <span class="toggle-yesterday">Yesterday</span> 
    | 
    <span class="toggle-WTD">WTD</span> 
</div>
```

Comment: Considering the code posted does neither, I think you are missing something. Can you post your span?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but I think you mean something like this:

```
$(".date-toggle").on("click" , function(){
    $(".date-toggle").not(this).removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');

    var day =  $(this).data('title');
    $('#daySelected').text(day);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/u94fvb2g/

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

So I actually found it easier to make it a "virtual" onclick event, as follows:

```
                    "tap .toggle-yesterday" : function() {
                       if (!$(".toggle-yesterday").hasClass("active")) {
                              $(".toggle-yesterday").addClass("active")
                              $(".toggle-today,.toggle-WTD").removeClass("active")
                              this.trigger("switchSalesDate", "yesterday", _.bind(this.updateSalesList, this));
                       }

                 },

                 "tap .toggle-today" : function() {
                       if (!$(".toggle-today").hasClass("active")) {
                              $(".toggle-today").addClass("active")
                              $(".toggle-yesterday,.toggle-WTD").removeClass("active")
                              this.trigger("switchSalesDate", "today", _.bind(this.updateSalesList, this));
                       }
                 },

                 "tap .toggle-WTD" : function() {
                       if (!$(".toggle.WTD").hasClass("active")) {
                              $(".toggle-WTD").addClass("active")
                              $(".toggle-today,.toggle-yesterday").removeClass("active")
                              this.trigger("switchSalesDate", "WTD", _.bind(this.updateSalesList, this));
                       }
                 },
```